# What are the common cases where you would want Puppeteer (not) in Incognito mode?

Tags: puppeteer

In their presentation, the developers say that Puppeteer is "based on incognito mode" in Chrome, but what does it mean?
It seems that either way it doesn't save the session information, so what are the cases where I would want and not want to use incognito mode explicitly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(I'm the OP)
So, I found out that the file system API is disabled in Incognito mode, so that's, I assume, should be the biggest difference in the context of Puppeteer